# Receiving Generic Class as Parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

I'm new at Generic Class. I'm making a game right now. I'll have many enemies, which all inherit from a generic EnemyBase class

```
public abstract class EnemyBase<TState, TTransition>
{
     protected StateMachine<TState, TTransition> m_FSM;
}
```

So as an example, I would have something like this:

```
public class EnemySquire : EnemyBase<EnemySquire.State, EnemySquire.StateTransition>
{
    public enum State
    {
        IDLE,
        WALK,
        ATTACKED,
        DEAD,
    }

    public enum StateTransition
    {
        FOUND_FREE_GRID,
        FINISHED,
        FREED,
        OUT_OF_LIFE,
        ATTACKED,
    }
}
```

So far so good. My problem is to receive `EnemyBase` class as parameter. I want to receive any kind of EnemyBase regardless of its generics. So:

```
public class Player
{
   public void Attack<TState, TTransition>()
   {
        EnemyBase<TState,TTransition> enemy = GetComponent<EnemyBase<TState,TTransition>>();
   }
}
```

This will work but Attack method is called inside another method so this other method must implement `<TState, TTransition>` as well and this other method is called by another one... and go on.

I would like to achieve something like:

```
public void Attack()
{
     EnemyBase enemy = GetComponent<EnemyBase>();
}
```

or

```
public void Attack()
{
     EnemyBase<,> enemy = GetComponent<EnemyBase<,>>();
}
```

I don't know if these sintaxes are correct or even if they exists but I just want to know if class is EnemyBase, regardless its generics.

Thanks

edit: added what generic type are used for

Comment: Define the common interface(s), and only do generics on the implementation side, that expose those interfaces. Avoid unnecessary inheritance (tight coupling).

Comment: In this case it must be generic because EnemyBase has a FSM and FSM receive those generic types: `protected StateMachine<TState, TTransition> m_FSM;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a field with an un-bound generic type like `EnemyBase<,>`.

You need to define either a non-generic base class for the generic one like `EnemyBase<TState, TTransition> : EnemyBase` or an interface like `EnemyBase<TState, TTransition> : IEnemy`.

Then you can have an `EnemyBase` or `IEnemy` field.

Comment: I implemented an interface with main methods so I could get from another class. I thought I could declare an un-bound generic type. It would be so much easier but interface did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
public interface IEnemy
{
     StateMachine m_FSM { get ; }
}

public abstract class EnemyBase<TState, TTransition> : IEnemy
{

    protected StateMachine<TState, TTransition> m_FSM;
    StateMachine IEnemy.m_FSM => this.m_FSM;
}

public class StateMachine
{

}

public class StateMachine<TState, TTransition> : StateMachine
{

}
```